# FileProvider.getUriForFile returns null

Tags: android, xml, image, android-fileprovider

I'm trying to take a photo in my device's camera, when I call the method that handles the image capture the app crashes because of a nullpointer exception. I don't know what information is missing with my FileProvider as the stacktrace points the nullpointer into my FileProvider.getUriForFile statement.

Here's my code
HomeActivity

```
public void takePhoto(View view){
        //camera stuff
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

        //folder stuff
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "AnimEncylopedia");
        if(!imagesFolder.exists()) {
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();
        }

        File image = new File(imagesFolder, "QR_" + timeStamp + ".png");


 Uri uriSavedImage = FileProvider.getUriForFile(HomeActivity.this, "com.encyclopedia.fileprovider", image);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
```

AndroidManifest

```
<provider
            android:authorities="com.encyclopedia.fileprovider"
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>

        </provider>
```

Files_path.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Encyclopedia/"/>
</paths>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use camera intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

in `onActivityResult()`

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getActivity(), photo);
```

It also depends on the camera app the user is using. With android camera it will work fine. But for other apps it depends whether they return a valid value for data or not.